# Inserting row in table - oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, insert-into

When I insert a row to a table which has some rows already in oracle, the new inserting row gets inserted somewhere middle instead of at the bottom of table. When inserting again a new row it follows below the row just added.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Tables in databases typically represent an *unordered* collection of data. In Oracle, tables are by default *heap-organized tables* and do not store data in order.

If ordering is important in your data, consider an *index-organized table*. For Oracle, more information on that can be found here: [Overview of Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT88806)

Sharing your table definition would help in confirming that for you.